# c# overlay an image on top of another

Tags: c#, png, overlay

i am currently trying to put the notes on top of the staff image. However, the notes background are being set to the form background as shown in the image. 
image type used is png.

[image]

```
//class music staff
  public MusicStaff(int xLoc, int yLoc, int xSize, int ySize)
        {
            this.SetBounds(xLoc, yLoc, xSize, ySize);
            this.Visible = true;
            ResourceManager rm = Resources.ResourceManager;

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("Staff1");
            this.BackgroundImage = bmp;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
//adding the background pic
   panel4 = new MusicStaff(3, 62, 927, 150);

//adding a note
 MusicNote p = new MusicNote(pitch, duration, shape, s);

            p.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            p.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            p.Size = new Size(50, 75);
 p.Location = new Point(xCounter + starterX, NoteLocations.c0.mainPoint);
                        Bitmap myImage = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject(shape);
                        p.Image = myImage;
```

Comment: Post any code you have for this so everyone can know where to start to help

Comment: ok added the code

Comment: The code looks a little truncated, which is good generally, but in this case I will need a little more to get some more context and see exactly what's going on.

Comment: To be transparent your bitmap needs to have an alpha channel. It can be created as such with the proper PixelFormat in the constructor, or with a call to the method MakeTransparent().

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 1):

You are not really overlaying images. You are overlaying controls with images.

For this to work with transparency, your notes controls **need to be nested** in the staff control!

As they aren't, the transparency shows the color of their actualy **parent**, i.e. the form.

Set `p.Parent=panel4`  and adapt the locations accordingly, i.e. make them relative to the staff..

This is a limitation of winforms transparency, which doesn't support **overlapping** controls. **Nested** controls will work fine but only by **faking** the transparent parts by copying them from the parent..

Note that as a consequence you will not be able to have the notes overlap each other or be overlapped by any other controls.

Often giving up on using controls is the better way; instead one can simply draw all parts that make up the total..

So you could do a series of `e.Graphics.DrawImage(noteImg, x, y)` in the `panel4_Paint` event.