# Moving PictureBox transparent background

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, picturebox

So I am trying to create an application in which I use png pictures in PictureBoxes. I am able to create those PictureBoxes with a transparent background, but when I move them around underneath the transparent places the background image looks kinda stuck.

So is there any way to leave the background as it is? I use the arrow keys as an input to choose direction, and I use a ticker to relocate the PictureBox.

Comment: Can you put what you try so far? It's winforms?

Comment: Yes it's in winforms. I have a player class in which I store directions and things like that.

Comment: Are you try `pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` and  `pictureBox.BringToFront();`?

Comment: yes, both of these things are in the code and the back really is transparent but only when i move it it looks somewhat strange behind it..

Comment: the timer looks like this

its too long to post

but i basically have a 'Player.x' and a 'Player.y' property which I change everytime the timer ticks, and then I have this line

'pictureBox1.Location = new Point(Player.x, Player.y);' which relocates the picturebox

Comment: A picturebox wont show controls "under" it because there are siblings which just happen to overlap.  They always show the parent background without a little code

Comment: In Winforms there is not __real__ but only __faked Transparency__. It will work __if and only if__ the control is __nested__ in another control.  It will __not__ work between __overlapping controls__. There is basically no way around this.. - Also noteworthy: you can __nest__ controls in `PictureBoxes` only using __code__, as it isn't a container. `pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;`  Also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051313/c-sharp-overlay-an-image-on-top-of-another/41055852?s=2|0.1857#41055852)